# Cannot connect to Remote React Server

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

This is my first time setting up a react project remotely. I cloned my react application on a remote GCP server and start it using `npm run start` command. When i `curl` the application address, I can see HTML output. However I cannot connect or telnet (to check the port connection) from my local machine. I know there is no issue on port or Firewall rule because I have a Spring Boot application running on the same machine. I tried starting it using the port for the react project and I was able to access the swagger page.

Comment: I don't understand, what does react-server have to do with telnet? If you can curl it, it works.

Comment: I am using telnet to verify the connection to the server via port works. It works when I do `curl http://localhost:8080` inside the server. But when I curl it in my local machine, it doesn't work

Comment: and what do you use to connect from your local machine? ip? domain? I think you have missed the whole http server configuration part... read this: https://react-server.io/docs/guides/production